# Htaccess rewrite rules - get method

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi i have another problem, i want to rewrite:

http://example.com/articles/page/id to http://example.com/?rt=articles&pageis=id

My code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^articles/page/(.+)$ index.php?rt=articles&pageis=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ index.php?rt=articles&title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^page/(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

First RewriteRule doesn't work, others works perfectly. Can somebody help me?
This is possible to rewrite this way?